# Can one optimize a function with min(x,y) as a constraint?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Let $$h(x,y) = \min\lbrace x,y \rbrace$$
I want to find 
$$\min ax + by$$ 
Subject to $$g(x,y) = c - h(x,y)= 0$$ 
My lagrangian is

$$L(x,y,\lambda) = ax+by + \lambda (c -  h(x,y)) $$

I have calculated

$$L_x = a - \lambda h_x(x,y) =0$$
$$L_y = b - \lambda h_y(x,y) =0$$
$$L_\lambda = c - h(x,y) =0$$
So 
$$\lambda = \frac{a}{h_x} $$
 $$\lambda = \frac{b}{h_y} $$

I know the partials for the $\min$ function. But this implies for $x<y$

$$ \frac{a}{1} =  \frac{b}{0}$$
and for $x>y$

$$ \frac{a}{0} =  \frac{b}{1}$$

I think this implies $\lambda$ is undefined over all intervals.

**My Question**
Have I misused the first order conditions somehow? Why am I getting nonsense answers? Shouldn't the optimum be $x=y$?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can apply [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method if $h(x,y)$ does not have continuous partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have for $x>y$, $ a=0, b=\lambda$, and for $x<y$ $ a=\lambda , b=0$.
Btw, your third derivative should be $c-h(x,y)=0$ and not $c-h_x =0$.
Now write $c=h(x,y)$, for the first case, $c= y$, so the minimum value is $cb$, for the second case the minimum value is $ac$.

Comment: How do you get $cb$ or $ac$? I don't follow although your conclusion seems to make sense since those values would make sense with the graph I have drawn.

Comment: For  $x>y$ , $h=y$, and subject to the constraint $h=c$ we have $y=c$, so from what we found on the lagrangian we know that a=0, and so the minimum of $ax+by$ is $bc$. For the other case reverse the roles of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Eccellente. Grazie amico!